# What *args, **kwargs doing in this save method overriding

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django. I understand what are the usage of  *args and **kwargs. And also know how to use them in method overriding.

But, I don't understand what purpose they serve while overriding the `save()` method in a model class.

My observation is that no number of arguments, either non-keyworded or keyworded, were assigned to them anywhere. Still why do I must use them and how.

Have this example:

```
class DemoModel(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) 
        super(DemoModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

From Django model documentation:

> It’s also important that you pass through the arguments that can be
>   passed to the model method – that’s what the *args, **kwargs bit does.
>   Django will, from time to time, extend the capabilities of built-in
>   model methods, adding new arguments. If you use *args, **kwargs in
>   your method definitions, you are guaranteed that your code will
>   automatically support those arguments when they are added.

Comment: Here, I don't understand what the *args and **kwargs in `def save(self, *args, **kwargs): ` is holding.

Comment: If you read the description of the save function you'll see there are arguments that you can pass to the persistence layer. Using `*args` and `**kwargs` is a way to future proof the interface if Django adds more arguments in future releases.

Answer (score -1):

Very late but,

You should add return to the save method.

`return super(DemoModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Secondly, the kwargs which means keyword arguments are also URL parameters that are passed to the views like `kwargs={"pk": self.object.id}` when you save the method and it needs to redirect to a detail view for example, it needs the id of the just created object. The magic happens already in Django views, but you can pass extra parameters if you want.

Comment: no you don't have to add the return statement

Comment: The `super()` call is required, but it doesn't have to be returned. Just end with `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`